# Group rows of data frame and work on them

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
mydata=data.frame(class = c("class 1", "class 2", "class 1", "class 2", "class 3",
                            "class 3", "class 1", "class 2", "class 1", "class 2",
                            "class 3", "class 1", "class 2", "class 3", "class 3"), 
                  word=c("A","B","A","C","A","B","A","C","D", "F", "G", "A", "U",
                         "A", "U"), weight=c(0.1,0.2,0.25,0.01,0.19,0.27,0.32,
                                             0.04,0.005,0.111,0.56,0.056,0.08,
                                             0.099,0.2345))
```

For each class, i.e. `class 1`, `class 2`, `class 3`, I would like to delect, from `mydata`, the first three words (see column `word`) with higher weights (see column `weight`). For my simple example, a code that realizes this task is:

```
x=table(mydata$class)
class=names(x)
y=mydata[mydata$class==class[1],]
y=y[order(y$weight,decreasing=TRUE),]
y=head(y,3)

z=mydata[mydata$class==class[2],]
z=z[order(z$weight,decreasing=TRUE),]
z=head(z,3)

w=mydata[mydata$class==class[3],]
w=w[order(w$weight,decreasing=TRUE),]
w=head(w,3)
```

And then, the desired result is:

```
> y$word
[1] A A A
Levels: A B C D F G U
> z$word
[1] B F U
Levels: A B C D F G U
> w$word
[1] G B U
Levels: A B C D F G U
```

If I had more classes, I would use for loop storing the words in a list. But ... Is there a more simple way to obtain this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>% 
  group_by(class) %>% 
  arrange(class, desc(weight)) %>% 
  slice(1:3)

#   class   word  weight
#   <fct>   <fct>  <dbl>
# 1 class 1 A      0.32 
# 2 class 1 A      0.25 
# 3 class 1 A      0.1  
# 4 class 2 B      0.2  
# 5 class 2 F      0.111
# 6 class 2 U      0.08 
# 7 class 3 G      0.56 
# 8 class 3 B      0.27 
# 9 class 3 U      0.234
```

---

Edit: the `slice` function selects the first 3 rows (in this case) for each group in the grouped dataframe. Unlike `top_n`, `slice` discards possible ties.

Comment: Thank you, no it's fine! I tried the solution, I noticed however that, if e.g. class 1 has the same weights the solution returns more than 3 occurrences. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Solution added in the answer. Unlike `top_n`, `slice` discards possible ties.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
setDT(mydata)
dt = mydata[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[order(weight, decreasing = T)][1:3]), keyby = class]

> dt
     class word weight
1: class 1    A 0.3200
2: class 1    A 0.2500
3: class 1    A 0.1000
4: class 2    B 0.2000
5: class 2    F 0.1110
6: class 2    U 0.0800
7: class 3    G 0.5600
8: class 3    B 0.2700
9: class 3    U 0.2345
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R approach with similar output to your request.

```
lapply(split(mydata,mydata$class),function(x){x[order(x$weight,decreasing=TRUE),"word"][1:3]})
$`class 1`
[1] A A A
Levels: A B C D F G U

$`class 2`
[1] B F U
Levels: A B C D F G U

$`class 3`
[1] G B U
Levels: A B C D F G U
```